# Linux of_platform_depopulate() does not remove drivers

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have a MFD driver that is populating child nodes from the device tree using `of_platform_default_populate()`. I am using this function instead of `devm_of_platform_populate()` because it uses `of_default_bus_match_table` that includes `simple-bus`.

It works well, but when calling `of_platform_depopulate()` the child driver is not unloaded. The child driver is a platform driver with the initialization code provided below. I can see in the log that calling `of_platform_default_populate()` results in  `cca_dma_remove()` function being executed, because "DMA driver removed" is present in dmesg. Yet `lsmod` still shows the driver being loaded. Do I need to do anything extra to get the driver totally removed? `rmmod cca_dma` works without any issues.

```c
static const struct of_device_id cca_dma_of_ids[] = {
    { .compatible = "cca,dma" },
    {}
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, cca_dma_of_ids);

static int cca_dma_remove(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    pr_info("DMA driver removed\n");
    return 0;
}

static struct platform_driver cca_dma_driver = {
    .driver = {
        .name = DEVICE_NAME,
        .of_match_table = cca_dma_of_ids,
    },
    .probe = cca_dma_probe,
    .remove = cca_dma_remove,
};
module_platform_driver(cca_dma_driver);
```

I am using Linux kernel v5.15.32.

Comment: Is your kernel built with CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD enabled?

Comment: That's normal behavior for Linux. Driver modules do not automatically unload when the last device is removed (unlike Windows plug-and-play drivers, for example). You could try unloading it using a UDEV rule if it bothers you.

Comment: Not tested, but some UDEV rule similar to this *might* work: `DRIVER=="cca_dma" ACTION=="remove" RUN+="/sbin/modprobe -r cca_dma"`.

Comment: `->remove()` callback means _"remove the **device instance**"_ and not a driver. It also known as "unbind the driver from the device".

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It is good to understand how it works, and to know that this is an expected behavior and not something I am doing wrong. The udev rule did not work but I can as well use a script unloading multiple drivers.

Comment: I'm not sure if the UDEV rule gets run just before or just after the device is removed. It wouldn't work if the rule gets run just before the device is removed because the module would still be in use by the device at that point!